# PrintWriter Sockets Stop responding after 1 time of sending data

Tags: java, sockets

Hello there. I am trying to send data from client to server, the first time it works, but the second time it stops getting the data. I don/t know what's wrong.

http://pastebin.com/Sc72aAqD

Basically it is a simple key logger, the wierd part is that it works for the first time, but the second time it doesn't get's response from the client.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a loop on the Client that reads lines from the server, and if the line is some particular String, you send a String back to the server.

On the server, it looks like you're reading 15 lines from the client. But I don't see anything that the server is sending back to the client. Wouldn't the client just block at:

```
while ((Client.f = in.readLine()) != null) {
```